# R Pagedown resume/cv lowercase letters for title

Tags: css, r, fonts, pagedown

I am working on creating a resume in R using Pagedown. Currently, the default is to have your name in all capital letters at the top of the first page (e.g. JANE DOE). However, this doesn't look great with my name and I am wondering if there is a way to edit just the title line to have mixed case (Jane Doe). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to remove the uppercase text transformation with CSS like that:

````
---
title: "Lijia Yu's resume"
author: Lijia Yu
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  pagedown::html_resume:
    # set it to true for a self-contained HTML page but it'll take longer to render
    self_contained: false
# uncomment this line to produce HTML and PDF in RStudio:
#knit: pagedown::chrome_print
---

```{css, echo=FALSE}
#title h1 {
  text-transform: unset;
}
```


Aside
================================================================================
...
````